# SQL Server - where cases in order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have following table:

```
ID | condition1 | condition2
1  | Y          | 0
2  | N          | 0
3  | Y          | 1
4  | N          | 1
```

I am searching for a query that gives me the results where `condition1` equals Y. But, if it doesn't equal Y, I want to check `condition2` and add those to my result where `condition2` equals 1.

So, my result would be:

```
ID | condition1 | condition2
1  | Y          | 0
3  | Y          | 1
4  | N          | 1
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

EDIT: I just realized my problem is not as simple as the example I wanted to give. (Totally my own fault). Since there are multiple answers who do give a solution to this (wrong) question, I won't edit it but just leave it like it is in case someone needs it in the future.

Comment: If you have two conditions but only one must be met, it is a classical `OR
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #B
    ([ID] INT, [CONDITION1] VARCHAR(1), [CONDITION2] INT)
;

INSERT INTO #B
    ([ID], [CONDITION1], [CONDITION2])
VALUES
    (1, 'Y', 0),
    (2, 'N', 0),
    (3, 'Y', 1),
    (4, 'N', 1)
SELECT [ID], [CONDITION1], [CONDITION2] FROM #B WHERE [CONDITION1]='Y' OR [CONDITION2]=1
```

output

```
ID  condition1  condition2
1   Y   0
3   Y   1
4   N   1
```

Comment: I just realize I asked my question the wrong way. You did, however, give a good answer on my wrong question so I will mark this one as the solution and leave the question here in case someone would ever need it. Thanks for the help :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, condtition1, condition2
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE condition1 = 'Y'
       OR (condition1 != 'Y' AND condition2 = 0);
```